# How do I update .NET Framework from 4.5.51209 to 4.5.51650?

Tags: .net, .net-framework-version

I have a Windows Server 2012 Standard machine with .NET Framework 4.5.51209. How do I update it to 4.5.51650?

Method used: [How to: Determine Which .NET Framework Updates Are Installed](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh925567(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is .NET Framework 4.5.2, and you can get it through Windows Update in most cases.  However, if it's not showing in WU, you can always download it directly from Microsoft.

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42642

FYI, I can find no legitimate reference to a version 4.5.51209, is this a beta version?  If so, it may not be supported to upgrade it.  You may have to uninstall and re-install from the latest download.

Or, alternatively, you may be looking in the wrong place to determine version number.  How are you doing this?

Comment: I believe 4.5.51209 is the version of .NET Framework 4.5.2 reported on Windows 7/2008R2.  4.5.51650 is the 4.5.2 version reported on Windows 8.1/2012R2.

Comment: @GregAskew - That may be... I wish MS documented this properly.